# Manually position an opentip tooltip in combination with Kinetic.js

Tags: javascript, tooltip, kineticjs

I'm making a web application that uses Kinetic.js for some fancy
graphical functions, and I want to show a tooltip with some information about each element when the users hovers over it.

I've already figured out how to invoke a function on hover with Kinetic.js:

```
myKineticObject.on("mousemove", function() {
    // Change content of tooltip depending on myKineticObject
    // Set position of tooltip to cursor position
    // Show tooltip
});

myKineticObject.on("mouseout", function() {
    // Hide tooltip
}
```

I've decided to use the seemingly nice [Opentip](http://www.opentip.org/) to show the tooltip.
The only problem is that Kinetic.js doesn't create any usable DOM elements to use as a target for opentip.

This is (roughly) what my HTML looks like:

```
<html>

    <head><!-- Styles --></head>

    <body>

        <div id="container">

            <canvas class = "kineticjs-buffer-layer">
            <canvas class = "kineticjs-path-layer">
            <canvas class = "myLayer1">
            <canvas class = "myLayer2">
            <!-- ... more layers -->

        </div>
        <!-- Scripts -->
    </body>

</html>
```

Important to know is that these canvas elements all have the same width and height and stack on eachother. So they're unusable as targets.

So instead of using a DOM element to use as the target for my tooltip, I need to 
manually show/hide and position the tooltip. 
I've figured out how to do the showing and hiding like this:

```
    var tooltip = new Opentip(
        "div#container", //target element 
        "DummyContent", // will be replaced
        "My Title", // title
        {
            showOn: null, // I'll manually manage the showOn effect
        });
```

I now do the following:

```
myKineticObject.on("mousemove", function() {
    tooltip.show();
});

myKineticObject.on("mouseout", function() {
    tooltip.hide();
}
```

The only problem is that it just shows up at the top left of the page, and I can't find anything in the docs on how to position this thing manually.

Suggestions or ideas welcome. I'm also open to using a different tooltip library, if necessary.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem like this, for those of you who are looking for a solution too:

```
group.on("mousemove", function(event) {

    tooltip.content = //change content 
    tooltip.show();
    $("#opentip-1").offset({ left: event.offsetX, top: event.offsetY });

});
```

Comment: I've recently improved the docs on that. You should use `tooltip.setContent()` to update the content instead of just setting it. As for the placement of the tooltip, `fixed: true` should theoretically work and appear at the cursor position... So you might have found a bug. I created an [issue](https://github.com/enyo/opentip/issues/22) and will look into it.

Answer (score 3):

It appears (with no knowledge of Opentip, besides a quick look at the docs) that you can set 'fixed' to true in the config. Since the target is null, the docs suggest fixed=true should make the tooltip appear at the mouse position, but not follow it once the mouse is moved around.

How does that sound?

Comment: I'll try this out tomorrow, and keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry the target false didn't work. See my answer for the solution that did it. Thanks anyway!